# Ruby Interactive List Creation

Tags: arrays, ruby

Just started Ruby.

Basically I am trying to write a code which will take users input from the terminal and create an array.

```
Type a student name:
felix
Type another student name or press enter to finish:
Cedric
Type another student name or press enter to finish:
bob
Type another student name or press enter to finish:

Congratulations! Your Wagon has 3 students:
bob, Cedric and felix
```

What I have done so far is below. Not sure if I need a loop? How can I fix the "else" ?

```
new_array = []
count = 0

puts "Type a student name"
name = gets.chomp
new_array << name
count = count + 1


puts "Type another student name or enter to finish"
name = gets.chomp
if name == ""
  puts "Congratulations! Your Wagon has #{count} student:
#{new_array[0]}"
else
  puts "Type another student name or enter to finish"
  name = gets.chomp
  new_array << name
  count = count + 1
  puts "Congratulations! Your Wagon has #{count} student:
#{new_array}"
end
```

Comment: When I enter a b and c I get this ---> Congratulations! Your Wagon has 2 student:
["a", "c"]

Comment: You get "a", "c" because you don't add the 2nd name to the array. There are 3 `name = gets.chomp` in your code, but only 2 `new_array << name`.

Comment: K I fixed that one and now I got this, and need to implement a loop here correct?

Comment: `code`   if name == ""
    puts "Congratulations! Your Wagon has #{count} student:
  #{new_array[0]}"
  else
    new_array << name
    count = count + 1
    puts "Congratulations! Your Wagon has #{count} student:
  #{new_array}"
  end

Comment: Without a loop, you'd be limited to 3 names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to enter an arbitrary amount of names, you need some kind of loop. Here's an example without an `else`-part using [`loop`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#loop-method) and [`break`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/doc/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-break+Statement):

```
array = []

puts "Type a student name"
loop do
  name = gets.chomp
  break if name.empty?

  array << name
  puts "Type another student name or enter to finish"
end
```

But with one `puts` outside and an additional `puts` at the loop's end, the code seem a bit out of order.

I'd prefer to keep each round's initial output at the top of the loop, even if the code becomes longer. This can be achieved by using `1.step` instead of `loop` which passes a 1-based counter into the block: (there are *many* other ways to do this)

```
1.step do |i|
  if i == 1
    puts "Type a student name"
  else
    puts "Type another student name or enter to finish"
  end

  name = gets.chomp
  break if name.empty?

  array << name
end
```

You also don't need to count the entered names yourself, just ask the array for its element [`count`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#count-method):

```
puts "Congratulations! Your Wagon has #{array.count} student(s):"
puts array.join(', ')
```

Comment: Thank you! It works, I need to modify a bit but this was what I needed :)